# Couldn't figure out why the relaying is denied

Tags: mailgun

Below is what happened to one mail send from a drupal client.

```
$ grep 'B6693C0977' /var/log/maillog
Jan 19 14:12:30 instance-1 postfix/pickup[19329]: B6693C0977: uid=0 from=<admin@mailgun.domainA.com>
Jan 19 14:12:30 instance-1 postfix/cleanup[20035]: B6693C0977: message-id=<20170119141230.B6693C0977@mail.instance-1.c.tw-pilot.internal>
Jan 19 14:12:30 instance-1 postfix/qmgr[19330]: B6693C0977: from=<admin@mailgun.domainA.com>, size=5681, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 19 14:12:33 instance-1 postfix/smtp[20039]: B6693C0977:
to=<username@hotmail.com>, relay=smtp.mailgun.org[52.41.19.62]:2525, delay=2.4, 
delays=0.02/0.05/1.8/0.53, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host smtp.mailgun.org
[52.41.19.62] said: 550 5.7.1 **Relaying denied** (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jan 19 14:12:33 instance-1 postfix/bounce[20050]: B6693C0977: sender non-delivery notification: ABB94C0976
Jan 19 14:12:33 instance-1 postfix/qmgr[19330]: B6693C0977: removed
```

Relevant excerpts from my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` are below

```
# RELAYHOST SETTINGS
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
```

and from `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` is follows

```
@mailgun.domainA.com postmaster@mailgun.domainA.com:password
```

and from `/etc/postfix/relayhost_map` is follows

```
@mailgun.domainA.com [smtp.mailgun.org]:2525
```

The permissions of the `db` files are as follows

```
# ls -lZ /etc/postfix/relayhost_map.db
-rw-r-----. root postfix unconfined_u:object_r:postfix_etc_t:s0 /etc/postfix/relayhost_map.db
# ls -lZ /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db 
-rw-r-----. root postfix unconfined_u:object_r:postfix_etc_t:s0 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
```

The problem is

- Outbound mails are not going.
- No logs are shown in mailgun console.

Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question now but I've just had the same issue and wanted to post a response for anyone who comes across this article in future.

I believe your issue is in `/etc/postfix/relayhost_map` where you should have the following, **note that there are no brackets**, for me it was the inclusion of brackets that was causing the issue:

```
@mailgun.domainA.com smtp.mailgun.org:2525
```

For anyone who is not using `/etc/postfix/relayhost_map` and is doing it all in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` directly the same applies:

```
smtp.mailgun.org:2525 postmaster@mailgun.domainA.com:password
```

Don't forget to regenerate the postfix sasl_passwd.db file and restart the service afterwards

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

Or `sudo service postfix restart` if you're on an older system / not running systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is realted to problems on their platform if everything was working ok previously just open a ticket and usually they fix it in a few hours (yes that its kind of hard a few hours)

Comment: will its being a few days since i am also getting this and mailgun its not doing anything to fix this